# Enter text to a Table Cell in a Doc file using apache poi in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, doc

Output:

[image: output]

I want to fill the 2nd and 4th cell of this table.
what I have tried:

```
//got this from an answer here.
  XWPFTable table = doc.getTableArray(0);
  XWPFTableRow oldRow = table.getRow(1);         //the cell is in the second row
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = oldRow.getCell(1).addParagraph();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph1 = oldRow.getCell(3).addParagraph();
  setRun(paragraph.createRun() , "Times New Roman" , 10, "2b5079" , "I want to enter this!" , true, false); //for 2nd cell
  setRun(paragraph1.createRun() , "Times New Roman" , 10, "2b5079" , "I want to enter this too!" , true, false);//for 4th cell

private void setRun (XWPFRun run , String fontFamily , int fontSize , String colorRGB , String text , boolean bold , boolean addBreak) {
        run.setFontFamily(fontFamily);
        run.setFontSize(fontSize);
        run.setColor(colorRGB);
        run.setText(text);
        run.setBold(bold);
        if (addBreak)
            run.addBreak();
    }
```

I also tried two or more similar ways to accomplish this but no luck. Why can't we just do `cell(1).setText("Hello World")`? (This is not working)

What is the way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot confirm that [XWPFTableCell.setText](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html#setText-java.lang.String-) does not work. For me it works using current `apache poi 4.1.2`.

Let's have a complete example:

My `WordTableExample.docx` looks like this:

[image]

Then this code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class WordFillTableCells {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordTableExample.docx"));

  XWPFTable table = document.getTableArray(0);
  XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(1);
  XWPFTableCell cell = row.getCell(1);
  cell.setText("New content of cell row 2 cell 2.");

  cell = row.getCell(3);
  cell.setText("New content of cell row 2 cell 4.");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./WordTableExampleNew.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

produces this resulting `WordTableExampleNew.docx`:

[image]